# How can I solve syntax error for the following code in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I have used the following code for optimizing a problem via `pyomo`, `coopr`.

However the compiler gives an error, as follows:

> invalid syntax

I tried to use correct syntax but I can not find the error:

```
model = AbstractModel()
model.x = Var(initialize = 1.5)
model.y = Var(initialize = 1.5)
import pyomo
from coopr.pyomo import *
def rosenbrock(model):
    return (1.0-model.x)**2 \
           + 100.0*(model.y - model.x**2)**2
model.obj=Objective(rule=rosenbrock, sense=minimize)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @fred_dot_u - Agreed, this should be migrated to SO. I have flagged it as such.

Comment: @Greenonline, how were you able to flag to migrate it to SO.  I don't get that option.  See https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224/flagging-a-question-for-migration

Comment: @markshancock - use the flag "In need of moderation attention" and then specify why it should be migrated ad where to. It doesn't always work, depending on the length of time that the question has been posted for and some other factors, but often it does,

Comment: I just run the script I dont recieve any syntax error. @iman are you running the script with line12?  I m using Python2.7

Comment: If you were in interactive mode, you need an empty line at the end of compound statements, such as function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

That code appears to be syntactically valid.  Indeed I have just successfully compiled it in Python 3.6

Two possibilities occur to me:

1. There is a problem with your line continuation.  Note that the backslash
   must be followed only by exactly the new line character. If you have additional white space then this will cause an error.  For that reason, Python programmers are recommended to avoid line continuation.
2. The environment in which this code is running is a specialised embedded Python with some special constraints of which I am not aware.

Hope one of these helps ...